# How to modify default style of AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I imported module to my project When AlertDialog is popping up it's in default style, how could i edit style or theme to change font color and add custom button?

```
class UpdateDialog {
    static void show(final Context context, String content, final String downloadUrl) {
        if (isContextValid(context)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle(R.string.android_title)
                    .setMessage(content)
                   .setPositiveButton(R.string.android_auto_update_dialog_btn_download, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            goToDownload(context, downloadUrl);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.android_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        }
                    })
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom xml layout file like "dialog" and the call it.

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
dialog.show();
```

In this way you can customize all you want.